Communication Between Docker Containers Running Different Versions of ROS
I have two Docker containers, each running ROS 1 and ROS 2. I need both to be able to read and publish topics from each other, and maybe even from the host. I know it's possible to use ros_bridge for the inter-version communication, but I'm not sure how to do this through a Docker network, since I believe it needs to know where (directory) each ROS version was installed.
Has anyone done something similar who can help me with examples, or even tell me if it's possible? I would like the communication to be as efficient as possible in terms of latency between the topic publication and its availability for reading.
And I can't change anything much about the nodes that publish and reads the topics, they're tools external to my project.
Thanks for the help and dedication.

Yes, it is possible to do anything with docker, starting with --net=host to open the networks between the containers.
If you need it as efficient as possible, do not mix both ROS 1 and ROS 2. To maximize efficiency, you need to run your nodes in the same process through composable nodes and potentially leverage shared memory if your messages are large.
ros_bridge uses JSON as the transport, which is not generally suitable for high bandwidth low latency communication between nodes.
To better understand the limitations of rosbridge in performant systems, I recommend watching this ROSCon talk.
I would recommend taking a look at your application as a whole, asking why you need both ROS 1 and ROS 2, and whether you need high performance between the two ROS versions, or whether that's ok to go across the ros_bridge transport given its overhead.

Thanks a lot for the answer! However, I need to use ros1 and 2 because of the external tools that my team uses and that I can't do much about. Would it be suitable for me to write a c++ executable that reads the topics and publishes it in both ros1 and 2 in a faster way then using JSON? Would it even be possible, in a not-extremely-hard way?

Yes, it is possible to use C++, link to both ROS 1 and ROS 2 and manually spin both nodes in the same process, however if you want to use LTS stable versions for both, it may be hard to compile. There is no overlap in Tier 1 support on Ubuntu between ROS 1 and ROS 2, so you will likely have to run Ubuntu 20 on Tier3 support.

Oh, I see. So maybe two C++ nodes? One for each ROS version, and that communicate somehow... haha this is tough

No, one node, that uses both ROS 1 and ROS 2 in the same process.

But wasn't it hard to compile both versions?

It depends on what your dependencies. Per ROS REP-2000, you can compile humble on Ubuntu 20.04 with tier 3 support. And ROS 1 noetic has binaries on Ubuntu 20.04.
